# jQuery Selector on Two Different Events

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following html

```
<button type="button">btn</button>
<input type="text" value="txt" />
```

I am also doing the following jQuery functions:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    // Do something
});

$('input[type=text]').change(function() {
    // Do the same thing as in button click
});
```

Now, I would like to combine both jQuery calls into one, something along the following pseudo code:

```
<$('button').click()> -- OR -- <$('input[type=text]').change()>
    // Do the common code
```

One suggestion might be to do the following

```
function do_something() {
    // Do common code
}

$('button').click(function() {
    do_something();
});

$('input[type=text]').change(function() {
    do_something();
});
```

Which would work, however I am looking for a "selector-event" solution, not a common function solutions (i.e., I would like to have the selector and the event be used to call an embedded function). Can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Since you have two different elements with two different events then no, the last solution you proposed would be the way most people do it.

Comment: @j08691 - I was hoping for a different answer than what you stated in your comment :(

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".event").on({
    input: function() {
        do_something();
    },
    click: function(e) {
        if (e.target.id == "btn") {
              do_something();
        }
    }
});

function do_something() {
    alert('I am Clicked so do common code here!');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="event" id="btn" type="button">btn</button>
<input class="event" id="input" type="text" name="myInput" value="txt" />
```

i just want to give answer by one line **we can not call two different events for different selector (input and button)**

Comment: Hi, and thanks. Both the button and textbox react to "on click". Notice that the event for the textbox in my original question is "on change", so it is a different event binding from "on click" for the button. I do not think this answer would work.

Comment: @Greeso Answer updated!!! Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Still did not work. The text box is calling the common code via click. This should not happen, click is only for buttons. Input is on change.. Thanks though.

Comment: @Greeso Bro answer updated :-) it was tricky but have done!!!

Comment: Hello again. Well, now you are down to the original problem that I requested not to happen, which is the common function `do_something()`, which I was trying to avoid in the first place (if you read the question, I was trying to have a common "inline" function for both types of events, not a common "external" function.. I really really appreciate your help and trying to solve the problem. So nice of you.

Comment: Hi we can not create on create one event to the function and  the reason is click event.

Comment: i think my updated answer is right. read last line !!!! and yes nice to e-meet you :-)